# How to remove header of a wavfile in Matlab

Tags: matlab, header, wav

I need to remove first 1024 bytes of a wave file. I tried to do but I got corrupted/distorted wavfile:

```
wavFile = fopen(fullFileName, 'r'); % Open file for reading 
fseek (wavFile, 1024, -1);% Skip past header, which is 1024 bytes long.
wF = fread (wavFile, inf, 'int16');% 16-bit signed integers
wF = wF(:)';
newWavFile = fopen(strcat('new_',fileNames(fileNo).name), 'w+');% Open file for reading
fwrite(newWavFile,wF);
fclose(wavFile);
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: Maybe because a WAV file with the first 1024 bytes chopped is, by definition, a corrupted WAV file? Are you trying to remove the first few milliseconds of the audio itself? or trying to remove some of the information in the header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could manage to remove header and correct the distortion by :

```
            wavFile = fopen(fullFileName, 'r');% Open file for reading 
            fseek (wavFile, 1024, -1);% Skip past header, which is 1024 bytes long.
            wF = fread (wavFile, inf, 'int16');% 16-bit signed integers
            wF = wF(:)';
            wF = 0.8*wF/max(abs(wF));
            newWavFile =strcat('1_',fileNames(fileNo).name);% Open file for reading
            wavwrite(wF,16000,16,newWavFile);
```