# writing audio signal to file using 16 bit per sample (LSB,MSB) in Matlab

Tags: matlab, file-io, endianness

could you help me with generation audio signal with such a parameters:

- sample rate = 8000 Hz,
- mono,
- 16-bits per sample.

I need write samples to file without any header, in little-endian representation with sign (LSB,MSB). E.g. if sample has value 32767 (it is maximum in this representation) then it will be saved as 0xFF7F.

This signal should contain couple of tones. I have such a code for generating tones:

```
 frequency = 2000;
 duration = 2;
 amplitude = 1;
 sampleFreq = 8000;

t = linspace( 0, duration, duration * sampleFreq );
s = amplitude * sin( 2 * pi * frequency * t ) + amplitude * sin( 2 * pi * frequency/2 * t ) + amplitude * sin( 2 * pi * frequency*2 * t );
```

It creates vector (mono) with 8000 Hz sample rate. But I don't know how to write samples in 16-bits with LSB,MSB convention.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can either use [wavewrite](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/wavwrite.html) or [audiowrite](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/audiowrite.html).
`wavwrite(s,filename)` writes the data stored in the variable `s` to a WAVE file called `filename`. The `filename` input is a string enclosed in single quotes. The data has a sample rate of 8000 Hz and is assumed to be 16-bit.
If there an endianess issue, you can format the  big-endian output into little-endian  (and vice versa) using the [swapbytes](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/swapbytes.html) function, i.e. `s =   swapbytes(s)`

you can remove the header using the [following SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369762/how-to-remove-header-of-a-wavfile-in-matlab)

Comment: Hi @natan. I made simpple test with saving such a vector: `ss = [32767;-32768;0;1;-1]`. It was saved as FF7F 0080 0000 FF7F 0080. It is probably because "Note that for floating point data where NBITS < 32, amplitude values are clipped to the range -1.0 <= Y < +1.0." I think I should first has vector signal as integers...

Comment: And there was also header. Alternatively I could remove it by hand, but maybe there is some better way to do it?

Comment: I'd use `uint16` and see my edited answer regarding the header.

Comment: Ok. I have now headerless file with correct (`int16` little endian) coding. My problem now is that the range of generated `s` signal is small, between -3.2268 and 3.2268. If I change it with `int16` I get obviously values -3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3. Could you suggest something to generate signal with wider range (but not with overflow for int16)?

Comment: normalize your signal to the max `int16` value, `y=int16(y./max(y)*32767)`